# how to print two strings in a line one with space delimiter and another between two strings in Linux

Tags: linux

I have a file with more than 100 lines.

But only some lines have specific pattern like `abc`.

My question is that I want two things to print

1. 5th word of line which has pattern `abc`.
2. words between 2 distinct strings `(xxx, yyy)`.

Say for example my file has the content below:

> This is first line.
>
> Second line has `abc` pattern with `xxx` as first separator and `yyy` as second separator.
>
> This is third line.
>
> Again fourth line has same pattern `abc` with separators `xxx` and `yyy`.
>
> And so on.

The required output is like below:

> pattern as first separator and 
>   same and

I tried many ways in Linux but if I was able to print 5th word then content between `xxx` and `yyy` I was not able to print and vice versa.

Can any one help me please?

Comment: Linux isn't a language; you haven't shown your "required output", nor any of your attempts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer to your question:

---

My question is that I want two things to print

1. 5th word of line which has pattern `abc`.
2. words between 2 distinct strings `(xxx, yyy)`.

---

You can use `awk` for both parts of your question:

1. `awk '/abc/{print $5}'` input_file.txt
2. `awk '/xxx.*yyy/{if(match($0,"xxx.*yyy)){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTGH)}}' input_file.txt`

if you need to combine both requirements in one command:

```
awk '/abc/{print $5} /xxx.*yyy/{if(match($0,"xxx.*yyy)){print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTGH)}}'
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
pattern
xxx as first separator and yyy
same
xxx and yyy
```